# Reporting results of a Quade test

Tags: nonparametric, ancova

I have been scouring the internet to find out how to report the results of a Quade test (non-parametric equivalent of ANCOVA).

Does someone have an example that explains this in plain terms? I'm not sure if I report an F test statistic, df etc.

Answer (score 1):

The Quade-Test is basically an ANCOVA with ranks instead of the actual data. The test statistic is calculated in a comparable way (comparison of the total sum of squares and treatment sum of squares) and is F-distributed.

You can report the Quade-Test the same way as you would report an ANCOVA. An example in APA-style (maybe add an effect size too):

> *F*(2, 14) = 10.620, *p* = .002